# Azure B4ms vm size and cpu credits

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm doing a load testing on a Azure vm. The vm size is b4ms type. I encounted the following behavior between cpu credits remaining and cpu usage. For b4ms, the base performance is 90% as per the documentation. The cpu usage was not exceeding 90% at any time, but the cpu credits were decreasing during the time. According to the concept of B series, it should be storing credits, since cpu usage is below the base performance. Any explanation to this behavior is highly appreciated.[image: please refer the image added]

Comment: I would check this article by one of our Product Group members which explains how the credits work. Might explain better than something else you found https://www.singhkays.com/blog/understanding-azure-b-series/

Comment: Thank you. Please update the post on the findings.